# ATEN IP8000 Ubuntu Support

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-video-mouse

I'd like to know if there have been any successful use of the [ATEN IP8000](http://www.aten.com/products/KVM-Switches/KVM-over-IP-Switches/Remote-Management-PCI-Card~IP8000.html) with Ubuntu.

I'm aware the official page doesn't list Ubuntu as a supported OS, but I'd like to know if it's still possible to use it with Ubuntu and what limitations/problems there might be. Would I be able to upgrade the firmware from an Ubuntu host? If it's not, can you suggest another similar product that would be supported? The only two hard requirements are power management and video support.

Also, this would be used with Ubuntu Desktop, not Server. This requirement would be flexible if the only way to make it work is with the server version, but I assume that makes no real difference.

Comment: The KVM interface of ATEN was Java, last time I tried. It *should* work on Ubuntu. - But don't take *my* word for it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not too worried about the KVM interface itself. But since this is a PCI card, I wonder if there might any interference or driver issues with an unsupported host OS. As far I understand how this would work, that doesn't sound very likely. However, ATEN specifically made a list of supported host OS, so I'm assuming there's a reason for that.

Comment: Ah, well the only limitation that I could imagine would be inability to configure the IPMI hardware through tools from the OS - which isn't strictly necessary. In the end, it's mainly a Kernel question, I believe, so no reason to believe that Ubuntu would fare worse than other distributions.

Comment: That's not exactly true.  The card likely works by becoming the primary video card for the machine.  If the OS doesn't have drivers, it's not going to work.  This isn't like the built in IPMI cards.